# OP_RETURN with bitcoind not working

Tags: transactions, dust, non-standard-transaction

I have created a raw transaction with the following hexstring which decodes to:

```
{
   "lock_time":0,
   "size":248,
   "inputs":[
      {
         "prev_out":{
            "index":1,
            "hash":"2fb04bcfcc164fbb9d5ad740c891e2599d904920386ab4e7f39bc1c87431218e"
         },
         "script":"483045022100c727a635fbd5e689888e60a10c6ce45855abb7ceeb2235004d815edae2555abb022059839448cdd52733280b6fdde09ee87b06ba090357e50fea178d8fe41d811ba9012103f515b50b5e7693b4d8fe3d5d25346f989b42ab43f65a0106808f844deff55f08"
      }
   ],
   "version":1,
   "vin_sz":1,
   "hash":"096328dc269ea7a060eb1c16ce8629cf81a5cff5766eb3f2ec97d81344854327",
   "vout_sz":3,
   "out":[
      {
         "script_string":"OP_DUP OP_HASH160 98ac2448db3e1a08cce87052513280cb20bafbf5 OP_EQUALVERIFY OP_CHECKSIG",
         "address":"1EvFvmzhiFWhaRfvvZupxxQvTMHJ79GGdb",
         "value":1,
         "script":"76a91498ac2448db3e1a08cce87052513280cb20bafbf588ac"
      },
      {
         "script_string":"OP_DUP OP_HASH160 f3223f468b6b81b4104b5b880d23b246c9c76711 OP_EQUALVERIFY OP_CHECKSIG",
         "address":"1PAaE9hEh1RNpoGuSJ6fw6wajziLptJSVv",
         "value":99998,
         "script":"76a914f3223f468b6b81b4104b5b880d23b246c9c7671188ac"
      },
      {
         "script_string":"OP_RETURN 68656c6c6f20776f726c64",
         "value":0,
         "script":"6a0b68656c6c6f20776f726c64"
      }
   ]
}
```

When I enter the command

```
bitcoind sendrawtransaction <hex-string>
```

I get the following message:

```
error: {"code":-26,"message":"64: dust"}
```

Will this be anything to with standard transactions? I am currently using 0.9.3 branch of the bitcoin client.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is this output:

```
  {
     "script_string":"OP_DUP OP_HASH160 98ac2448db3e1a08cce87052513280cb20bafbf5 OP_EQUALVERIFY OP_CHECKSIG",
     "address":"1EvFvmzhiFWhaRfvvZupxxQvTMHJ79GGdb",
     "value":1,
     "script":"76a91498ac2448db3e1a08cce87052513280cb20bafbf588ac"
  },
```

See the `"value":1`? That means that the output is worth 1 satoshi. It's worthless, because it would cost more to spend this than it's worth. See [this answer](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/a/14255/2306) for more.

To solve this, remove that output.